# Nodejs+socket.io cannot find module

Tags: node.js, socket.io, debian, raspberry-pi

i try to follow this tutorial (http://www.radiusdesk.com/getting_started/install_ubuntu_node.js)
and i stuck on the nodejs step.

I installed nodejs but theres a problem with the socket.io module.

Log -> http://pastebin.com/DK2XSSeM

I used sudo npm -g install socket.io@0.9.x to install../usr/local/lib/node_modules/socket.io exists..

OS: Raspian 
(raspberrypi)

Thanks :)

Comment: Could you please post some of your code? I think I know what your problem is, but I can't be sure without your code.

Comment: You need to install it locally to your app without `-g`.

Comment: Are you sure node and npm installed fine, right? Can you try installing socket.io in your project folder (without -g), I dont't remember installing it as a general package.

Comment: paste.debian.net/116541 (nodejs-socket-io)

Answer (score 0):

Socket.io is not a global node module. You need to install it locally in the project and require() it use it in the code.

```
npm i --S socket.io
```

Then,

```
let socket = require('socket'); // something like that
```